# Git and binary files history

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

<sup>This is a follow up on some similar "*answered*" questions about [git handling binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697216/is-git-good-with-binary) and how [git can't follow file history very well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797099/274502).</sup>

So, *git can't properly follow file history*. Heck, even `git log --follow -M100% --name-only -- path-to-my-file` won't do it, and I'm [supposedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520023/how-does-git-track-history-during-a-refactoring/3520055#3520055) telling it to only follow files that are 100% similar!

Then [we are supposed to use other ways](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Directory-renames-without-breaking-git-log-td837434.html) to find who to *blame*, such as *bisecting*. Problem here is: those doesn't seem to work with binaries. And [accodring to Linus](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/git-version-control/07oWjHiQTtg) we are unlikely to get a `git log --follow` fully working any time soon.

In the end **my question here is**:

Do we have any automated way to enable some kind of `git log` to follow renamed / moved binaries?

Or maybe is there any similar *Version Controlling System* but with this functionality?

As an example of a kind of solution, I would accept some safe and simple way of [using `filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656404/git-move-files-in-history-too), but I never toyed with it and got no idea how dangerous it might be. Would we be able to pull and push without issues after issuing such a procedure? Can we easily revert it? Can we track the old names / references without reverting? You know, in a versioning system access to history is everything.

Comment: i hardly do versioning nowadays... but if i would try it again, i would try fossil-scm. this also means we probably have better options today!

Answer (score 0):

filter branch is safe. Just don't change anything in the script you provide. I'm annoyed at the -M option too. 100% doesn't work for regular files either. Try it.

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I'm concerned, rewriting history is always dangerous. Will it properly be pulled and pushed among cloned repos? Will I be able to easily revert it, at any time? Can I track back the old name without reverting it?

Comment: make a backup if you like. But index filter and work tree filter do nothing except execute what you say to execute for each commit it goes over.

Comment: This is not so urgent I'd go through the trouble of backing up and testing all that... But you didn't answer any of the questions! :D